# Right CSS Code on Javascript

Tags: javascript, css

I got this code and it seems not working:

```
var widthrel = 1366 - width;
var minusp = widthrel / 2;
var final = 10 - minusp;

document.styleSheets[0].addRule('.main-container:before','left:'+ parseInt(final) + 'px');
document.styleSheets[0].insertRule('.main-container:before {left:'+ parseInt(final) + 'px;}', 0);
document.styleSheets[0].addRule('.main-container:after','right:'+ parseInt(final) + 'px');
document.styleSheets[0].insertRule('.main-container:after {right:'+ parseInt(final) + 'px;}', 0);
```

can you help me with this?

Comment: what are you trying to achieve, can you create a fiddle on jsFiddle.net?

Comment: I need to change the css of the pseudo element upon browser width changes... @gurvinder372

Comment: I don't know if my code on this part is correct: document.styleSheets[0].addRule('.main-container:before','left:'+ parseInt(final) + 'px');

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
if(document.styleSheets[0].addRule) { //IE9, Chrome
    document.styleSheets[0].addRule(".main-container:before","left: "+parseInt(final)+"px;")
    document.styleSheets[0].addRule(".main-container:after","right: "+parseInt(final)+"px;")
} else if(document.styleSheets[0].insertRule) { /// Opera
    document.styleSheets[0].insertRule(".main-container:before {left: "+parseInt(final)+"px;}",0)
    document.styleSheets[0].insertRule(".main-container:after {right: "+parseInt(final)+"px;}",0)
}
```

Comment: Its work. I set var width=700 and take:

.main-container::before {
    left: -323px;
}

Comment: Sorry @SergT It works when I remove the other lines on my code. It overwrite the css code. Thanks Again

Comment: Other lines in you code can show error if you dont set var 'width'. You set that var?

Comment: the problem now @SergT is that the Firefox is not executing the code. I know that addRule is not recognize by Firefox only the insertRule. Regrading the 'width' it is the detection for the width of the browser(onLoad and onResize)

Comment: You error in 'width' == undefined I think ... Can you show console with errors from Firefox? Maybee 'width' is not global? Or set value of 'width' with errors?

Comment: no @SergT I did resolve the issue by first Identifying if it is a Firefox browser then apply the  head.appendChild(style) code on the if statement.